# How do I Scroll parent page to a Hashtag when child page is click within iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, parent

When I use `window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)` it works perfectly to the top of the parent page. But, when I need to go to a specific element, I can't figure out how to do so. I have tried `window.parent.scrollTo('#xyz')` and `window.parent.scrollTo($('#xyz'))`, but neither work.

Currently I'm using `window.parent.scrollTo(0,2500)` but it has issues on different device types.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTo()` can only scroll to a specific pixel from the top. The distance between the top of the page and the top of any element can be found in jQuery with `element.offset().top`. Combine the two:

```
window.parent.scrollTo(0, $('#xyz').offset().top)
```